Is including all pair-wise interactions in a three-way interaction linear regression model necessary?
I am trying to assess the impact of X on Y with Z as a control and a dummy variable (D), which takes a value of 0/1. However, to test my hypothesis, I have interacted with XZD as I want to see the heterogeneous impact of X on Y as Z changes when D takes the value 1.
My specification is Y = a + bX + cZ + eD + fXZ*D, and the coefficient f is statistically significant and confirms the magnitude outlined by the theory.
My question is, do we need to include all pair-wise interactions in the model, too? I tried including them and estimating the results, and now all the coefficients are insignificant, including f.
I could not find any theory on the inclusion/exclusion of interaction terms on the web, and I am new to applied econometrics. Any help would be appreciated.
